# JavaScript ошибка, хотя данные приходят верно

Tags: javascript

При выполнении кода, данные приходят, но после окончания выполнения цикла получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
> at axio.js:18

```
const instance = axios.create({

    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'fields': 'id,login,name,email'
    }
});
instance.get(proxyurl + url)
    .then(response => {

        for (let i = 0; i <= response.data.length; i++) {
            let s = response.data
            console.log(response.data[i].id)
        }

    })
```

Comment: Очевидно элемента `response.data[response.data.length]` не существует, потому что выходит за правый край массива, а вы пытаетесь к нему обратиться

Comment: Тоочно! Спасибо!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const instance = axios.create({

    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'fields': 'id,login,name,email'
    }
});
instance.get(proxyurl + url)
    .then(response => {

        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            let s = response.data
            console.log(response.data[i].id)
        }

    })
```

(спасибо @andreymal)